# Python stuck in while loop while trying to reach a list via input

Tags: python-3.x, list, input, while-loop

I'm new in Python and need your help regarding the below problem.

- The user is suppose to guess numbers which are part of list
- Problem: I don't get it how to make a loop which prompts the user for a number until the typed number is part of the list. Then the loop should be over.

I have managed to make it till the point where the loop never stops :/

I'll be so thankful if you guys can not only show me the correct way to do it, but also to explain shortly how am I suppose to do loops for lists (not creating them with loops)

- The code:

  ```
  #Checks if the customer's input is part of the list

  lst=[3,6,8,9]
  guess=int(input("Type a number and check if it's part of the list:"))

  while guess != lst:
     print("try again")
     guess=int(input("Type a number and check if it's part of the list:"))
  else:

     print("Congrats!")
  ```

  Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Comment: An integer will never be equal to a list.

Comment: Use `while guess not in lst:` instead.

Comment: might want to use `guess in lst`

Comment: Thank you for the fast answers guys! Problem solved! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make an infinite loop using bool True and break the loop when condition is true.

```
lst=[3,6,8,9]
while True:
  guess=int(input("Type a number and check if it's part of the list:"))
  if guess in lst:
      print("Congrats")
      break
  else:
      print("Try Again")
      continue
```